# Странное задание

Tags: егэ

Задание из сборника заданий для подготовки к ЕГЭ.
В одном из заданий нужно найти предложение, которое связано с предыдущим с помощью **формы слова, однокоренных слов и союза**. В ответах указано предложение **12**. Не понимаю, где тут формы слова:
Союз есть - "а", однокоренные слова есть: несколько | сколько. Но форм я не вижу, т.к. рассказать и рассказывают являются однокоренными словами. Может, вы подскажете?

> (11)Рассказывают про одного музыкального и художественного критика,
> который несколько лет назад в клубе художников, желая прочесть лекцию,
> минут пять изображал из себя молчаливую, смущённую статую: постоял на
> эстраде, помялся, да с тем и ушёл, не произнеся ни одного слова. (12)А
> сколько историй можно бы было рассказать про жрецов науки, которые
> «изводили» своих слушателей и в конце концов возбуждали к науке
> полнейшее отвращение.

Comment: Это Цыбулько? В интернете есть это задание. Но там предлагается найти предложение, которое связано с предыдущем при помощи союза и формы слова. Тогда все верно. Рассказывают и рассказать — Форма слова. Союз — а.

Comment: В вашем же задании нет олнокрненых слов.

Comment: Формы слова не могут различаться словообразующими суффиксами!

Comment: И в интернете не может быть этого задания, сборник 24 года.

Comment: Верно, но в нашем случае у нас глаголы не разного вида, а инфинитив и глагол в настоящем времени мн.ж.ч. первого лица. А это форма глагола.

Comment: Но оно есть (это задание). Только там надо найти формы слова и союз.

Comment: @Серж Инфинитив - это неопределенная форма глагола. У любого глагола есть эта форма. Рассказывать и рассказать - это глаголы разных видов = разные слова. Инфинитив считается лишь одной из форм глагола (главной), но все же формой, но это никак не объединяет глаголы разных видов под одним инфинитивом. У каждого глагола свой инфинитив: у расскажут - рассказать, у рассказывают - рассказывать.

Comment: Вы не поняли. В тексте глагол рассказывают. А не рассказывать.

Comment: @серж Как это влияет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11. **Рассказывают** про одного музыкального и художественного критика, ***который*** несколько лет назад в клубе художников, желая прочесть лекцию, минут пять изображал из себя молчаливую, смущённую статую: постоял на эстраде, помялся, да с тем и ушёл, не произнеся ни одного слова. (12) **А** сколько историй можно бы было **рассказать** про жрецов науки, **которые** «изводили» своих слушателей и в конце концов возбуждали к науке полнейшее отвращение.

Однокоренные слова: ***сколько, несколько, рассказать, рассказывать.***

Формы: ***который, которые.***

Союз **А.**

Comment: https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200404004#:~:text=%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%8B,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: "Глаголы разных видов, как бы ни были они близки по значению, являются не формами одного и того же глагола, а различными словами. Изменение видового значения у глаголов происходит при образовании от них посредством приставок и суффиксов производных глаголов",

Comment: У меня формы: который, которые, а глаголы однокоренные.

Comment: Но у нас ведь не рассказывать, а рассказывают.